# Ha cambiado el editor de snippets y algunas respuestas han dejado de funcionar

Tags: discusión, soporte

El editor de StackOverflow ha cambiado, o más en particular, el editor de snippets que permite ejecutar código dentro de las preguntas/respuestas. La manera en la que se ejecutan ahora los snippets es en un modo sandbox que no permite el envío de formularios, recibiendo el siguiente mensaje en Chrome:

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Esto hace que snippets que utilizaban en el evento `submit` de un formulario (incluso aquellos en los que se hace `preventDefault` para que no se envíe) hayan dejado de funcionar. No sé cuántos posts pueden ser, yo me he dado cuenta viendo una respuesta que hice hace algún tiempo.

¿Qué deberíamos hacer en esos casos?

Comment: yo tambien me di cuenta hace poco pero pense que el fallo era mio y  no que hubiera cambiado el editor xD En esos casos, deberiamos poner un enlace a algun snippet externo a SOes?

Comment: Tal vez reemplazar los botones de submit por botones corrientes y añadir la salvedad al texto de la respuesta?

Comment: Alvaro, puedes publicar la pregunta en el sitio Meta de Stack Exchange. Si es un bug, es en ese sitio quienes deberían revisar o informar si hubo cambios.

Comment: @amenadiel lo solucioné cambiando el evento `onsubmit` por un `onclick` en el botón de envío. El problema es que entonces requiere cambios adicionales porque `this` ya no es el formulario.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave voy a ver si alguien ha puesto algo en el sitio de stack exchange. Gracias por la sugerencia. A

Comment: Esto tiene pinta de [meta-tag:bug], ¿no?

Comment: Lo puse en [meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292745/274671) con el tag de bug

Comment: Solucionado ya ^^ https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292771

Comment: @lois6b será cuestión pues de añadir una respuesta para darlo por cerrado.

Comment: @fedorqui Hahaha no se si es una indirecta. pero creo que Álvaro debería ser el que contestara xD

Comment: @lois6b /me silba... :D Jajaja es que me da pereza publicarlo yo, que no he tenido nada que ver

Comment: @fedorqui yo tampoco xD

Comment: Ya lo pongo yo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [sugerencia de Mauricio Arias](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1608/ha-cambiado-el-editor-de-snippets-y-algunas-respuestas-han-dejado-de-funcionar?noredirect=1#comment4557_1608), añadí una [pregunta en Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292745/274671) y recibió atención bastante rápido.

Jarrod Dixon, uno de los desarrolladores de StackOverflow, añadió el token `allow-forms` al [atributo `sandbox` del iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe) que contiene los snippets y con eso se debería haber solucionado el problema. Para más referencia y detalles, ver [su respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292771/274671) (en inglés)

Comment: Gracias por preocuparte y hacerte cargo de que se llegue a mejorar la calidad de las respuestas